# Camel-Kafka SSL

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka, apache-camel

Can someone say form which version of camel-kafka or other related jars have these following Kafka SSL Properties for producer and consumer.

sslKeyPassword
sslKeystoreLocation
sslKeystorePassword
sslTruststoreLocation
sslTruststorePassword

Comment: All Kafka clients should set these. Camel, or not

Comment: @cricket_007  actually that is fine . But I am specifically using camel kafka for producer and consumer and need to k or from which version of camel -kafka jar it is applicable .

Comment: It's probably since the earliest version, so all of them. Those properties would just get passed down into the regular Kafka libraries